# Slow ftp upload. Upload gets faster when connected to team viewer

Tags: ftp

We are facing a very weird issue related to FTP upload. We have a 25mbps internet leased line but the ftp upload speed is very low about 25kbps. However, if we connect to a machine over team viewer then the upload speed gets high upto 1-2mbps. This is a very weird issue and i am digging out Google since last three days but no luck so far.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Please check with your internet service provider about maximum upload speed given for your leased line.

Check this website http://www.speedtest.net/ to test available bandwidth.
Important! internet speed get shared if multiple people use the same connection

Comment: Everything is working fine except ftp upload. However, the upload speed is good when we are connected to a different machine through team viewer. And the moment we disconnect the team viewer the upload speed comes down to 25-50kbps. This is what i have observed so far during the diagnosis. A very weird issue.